# Using Request as dependency for another service in Silex

Tags: dependency-injection, silex, service-provider

My web-service should check a specific GET param which comes in with every request. Depending on this parameter, I want to define a Service. 
Absence of this parameter is exceptional situation and should be handled.

Something like this:

```
    $app['myService'] = function (Application $app) {
        $param = $app['request']->query->get('param');

        if (empty($param)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Param must be defined');
        }

        return new MyService($param);
    }
```

1. Is it appropriate for Service to depend on Request?
2. Is this ok to check param value and throw an exception on registering? I'd utilise it in before() middleware, but is it enough to be sure that service instantiation will always work fine?
3. I'd like to create a Service Provider for this, but can't really get Request Service there, it fires up the exception "Accessed request service outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or controller". Looks like it suggested to move it to before() as well. What would you suggest?

Comment: 3. Seems that Request is not initilized by this time. How and when you use this service?

Comment: @MaxP. yeah, i agree. Is it me, or Silex doesn't allow to use request in registering Service Providers? Cannot figure out.
I use my service all over the application, particularly in controllers. It's a service i do calls to external API with. And one of the params needed for configuring this API client comes in with GET. So my idea is to catch it, configure and use freely in my app.

Comment: Silex doesn't allow, because Request is not set and filled with data at this time. Do you try to use `$app['request']` before `$app->run()`?

Comment: Describe where do you use this service except controllers?

Comment: @MaxP. Yes, I call $app['request'] before $app->run(). In registering service, like in the code sample i've shown in the question.

Comment: @MaxP. Yeah. You've raised a good point. I use it in app's before() middleware. And actually I've overhauled the code and now I do checks in this middleware, which is logically correct. Throw whatever Exceptions I need. And then (if everything's ok) just define an app param $app['myParam'] = $app['request']->query->get('param'); Then use it to register myService. Instead of calling Request. Thus i avoid any validations in service registering. Looks good to me. What do you think?

Comment: I think that it correct decision